# javascript_include_tag not working in rails 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2

The rails tag to include javascript , and for browser caching:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag '/skin/js/html5.js', :cache => true %>
```

forget about caching simple javascript_include tag is also not working.
Ex:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag '/skin/js/html5.js', :cache => true %>
```

But the script tag below is working find stop working after doing this.

```
<script src="/skin/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

using Rails 2 any reason for such a behavior or this tag did not even work in rails2?

Answer (score 2):

Try

First make sure that you are including the tag inside the head

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <script src="skin/js/html5.js"></script>
<% end %>
```